# WPF ViewModel overriding values set declaratively in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have the following user control:

```
<HMIClasses:vhMotor  x:Name="vhDevice" 
                         AutoSize="{Binding AutoSize,Mode=TwoWay}"
                         DeviceColour="{Binding DeviceColour,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                         MotorOn="{Binding MotorOn,Mode=TwoWay}"                             
                         DeviceSize="{Binding DeviceSize,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                         LayoutDirection="{Binding LayoutDirection,Mode=TwoWay}"
                         Speed="{Binding Speed,Mode=TwoWay}"
                         HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalAlignment,Mode=TwoWay}"
                         VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalAlignment,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                         Margin="{Binding Margin,Mode=TwoWay}" >
```

This is bound to the datacontext of the (this) user control here:

```
   public ucMotor() : base()
        {
            Initialise();
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = CreateViewModel()
        }
```

When I place the user control in XAML, the DependenyProperties are only applied when I edit them. What I mean is, if I declare the user control and specify properties as such:

```
  <local:ucMotor x:Name="motor1" 
                       DeviceColour="Red"
                       MotorOn="True"
                       Speed="Superspeed"
```

....Sure enough the control responds to the changes within the designer.

If I close and reopen form, the control appears with the properties of the view model and does not reflect those of the XAML. For example, the view model's default colour is silver and the control appears in silver despite the XAM specifying red.If I edit the XAML, the user control is refreshed in the correct colour.

This is my first attempt at user controls and dependency properties, so can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can we get a small sample of this please? How about a sample control, with a single dependency property, but showing how you have implemented it as well as how you use it.

Comment: UserControls with their own view model are a smell.  They should  be usable with the VM of the application/window within which they are being used.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and advice. The approach I had taken was unnecessarily complicated. I separated the user controls into 2 distinct classes, rather than having one embedded within another. This means that I don't have conflicting view models.